# Finder Services - Cannot get specific service to appear/run

Tags: terminal, finder, automator, services

I cannot get the default Finder "New Terminal at folder" service to work, no matter what. I've tried every trick I could find online.

So I created a new service and it appears in the Services list, but again, cannot get it to appear in the actual services menu nor does mapping a hotkey work.

**The kicker is that this exact service was working for the last few months with no issues**. Suddenly just stopped working. I haven't updated the OS or anything.

I'm on Sierra.

The script is below:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Finder"

        set myWin to window 1

        set theWin to (quoted form of POSIX path of (target of myWin as alias))

        tell application "Terminal"

            activate

            tell window 1

                do script "cd " & theWin

            end tell

        end tell

    end tell

    return input

end run
```

I really need this service to work, it saves me so much time and I really hate how it's not a reliable os feature.

Answer (score 1):

**macOS Sierra** has two built-in **Terminal Services**, **New Terminal at Folder** and **New Terminal Tab at Folder**.

Go to **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services** > **Files and Folders**, and check one or both and add a keyboard shortcut if you’d like.

Then in **Finder** you can select a **Folder**, right-click and select the *service* from the **Services** context menu, or from the **Finder** > **Services** menu or use the keyboard shortcut if assigned.

---

There’s no need to use **AppleScript** unless you really want to.

Here's some *example* **AppleScript** *code* that works of me:

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        set theTargetPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (target of front window as string) as string)
    end tell
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "pushd " & theTargetPath & "; clear"
        activate
    end tell
end try
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and aside from the use of a `try` *statement*, does not employ any additional *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: I do not have Services > Terminal, only Services > Files and Folders. I have checked both and added a shortcut, and it still will not appear in the menu. I restarted my computer, and the AppleScript option is now working. No idea why it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @Karric, Yes, it was supposed to be "Files and Folders", I just had Terminal on my mind. That said, why not use the built-in services over rolling your own?